# How do I delete a directory with read-only files in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, readonly, delete-directory

I need to delete a directory that contains read-only files.  Which approach is better:

- Using `DirectoryInfo.Delete()`, or,
- `ManagementObject.InvokeMethod("Delete")`?

With `DirectoryInfo.Delete()`, I have to manually turn off the read-only attribute for each file, but `ManagementObject.InvokeMethod("Delete")` doesn't appear to need to.  Is there any situation where one is more preferable to the other?

Sample code (test.txt is read only).

#### First way:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\");
dir.CreateSubdirectory("Test");

DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test\");
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\test.txt", @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test\test.txt");
File.SetAttributes(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test\test.txt", FileAttributes.Archive);
test.Delete(true);
```

#### Second way:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\");
dir.CreateSubdirectory("Test");

DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test\");
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\David\Desktop\test.txt", @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test\test.txt");

string folder = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Test";
string dirObject = "Win32_Directory.Name='" + folder + "'";
using (ManagementObject managementObject = new ManagementObject(dirObject))
{
    managementObject.Get();
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = managementObject.InvokeMethod("Delete", null,
    null);
    // ReturnValue should be 0, else failure
    if (Convert.ToInt32(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Here is an extension method which sets `Attributes` to `Normal` recursively, then deletes the items:

```
public static void DeleteReadOnly(this FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo)
{
    var directoryInfo = fileSystemInfo as DirectoryInfo;    
    if (directoryInfo != null)
    {
        foreach (FileSystemInfo childInfo in directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos())
        {
            childInfo.DeleteReadOnly();
        }
    }

    fileSystemInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    fileSystemInfo.Delete();
}
```

Comment: I have a situation where using this code deletes all the files and directories. Then when the process exits two empty folders reappear. I delete them manual and they stay disappeared.

Comment: I've added this answer in the comments of a handful of other similar questions that are using the removal of RO instead of setting to normal. Your method is better.

Comment: I had to add this line of code just before the `Delete()` operation: `fileSystemInfo.Refresh()`. Otherwise I got an `Exception` saying the directory is not empty.

Comment: Note that we need to skip directory logic when the fileSystemInfo is symbolic link or junction. So I recommend that checking `fileSystemInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)` before calling `GetFileSystemInfos()`.

Answer (score 105):

Simplest way of avoiding recursive calls is by utilising the `AllDirectories` option when getting `FileSystemInfo`s, like so:

```
public static void ForceDeleteDirectory(string path) 
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };

    foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    }

    directory.Delete(true);
}
```

Comment: The SearchOption argument was added to GetFileSystemInfos with.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 10):

Try this,

```
private void DeleteRecursiveFolder(string pFolderPath)
{
    foreach (string Folder in Directory.GetDirectories(pFolderPath))
    {
        DeleteRecursiveFolder(Folder);
    }

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(pFolderPath))
    {
        var pPath = Path.Combine(pFolderPath, file);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pPath);
        File.SetAttributes(pPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    Directory.Delete(pFolderPath);
}
```

Comment: *FileInfo fi* is useless

Answer (score 6):

Another method without the need for recursion.

```
public static void ForceDeleteDirectory(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo root;
    Stack<DirectoryInfo> fols;
    DirectoryInfo fol;
    fols = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
    root = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    fols.Push(root);
    while (fols.Count > 0)
    {
        fol = fols.Pop();
        fol.Attributes = fol.Attributes & ~(FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Hidden);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in fol.GetDirectories())
        {
            fols.Push(d);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo f in fol.GetFiles())
        {
            f.Attributes = f.Attributes & ~(FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Hidden);
            f.Delete();
        }
    }
    root.Delete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void DeleteRecursiveFolder(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
{
    foreach (var subDir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        DeleteRecursiveFolder(subDir);
    }

    foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Attributes=FileAttributes.Normal;
        file.Delete();
    }

    dirInfo.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Great solution, I stole it from you and just added a check before the dirInfo.Delete(); to see if the directory itself was read-only, would throw an exception in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to mark all the files as non-read only, and then delete the directory.

```
// delete/clear hidden attribute
File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) & ~FileAttributes.Hidden);

// delete/clear archive and read only attributes
File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) 
    & ~(FileAttributes.Archive | FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```

Notice that ~ is a Bitwise logical operator which returns the complement of the given binary value. I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your first approach looks more explicit and readable. The second method smells like reflection, is not type safe and looks weird. The `ManagementObject` can represent multiple things, so it's not obvious that `.InvokeMethod("Delete")` actually deletes a directory.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, using the WMI approach seems more efficient than iterating over the entire file system (assume for example the directory has 10's of thousands of files). But I do not know that WMI also doesn't do iterations. If it does, being closer to the metal (again, assumptions) it should be more efficient.

For elegance, I concede the recursive method is cool.

Performance testing should answer the efficiency question. And either can be elegant if wrapped in an extension method of DirectoryInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that avoids recursion on itself.

```
public static void DirectoryDeleteAll(string directoryPath)
{
    var rootInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };
    foreach (var fileInfo in rootInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()) fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var subInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subDirectory) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };
        foreach (var fileInfo in subInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()) fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    }
    Directory.Delete(directoryPath, true);
}
```

This works by resettings attributes on the folders and files before the delete, so you could just remove the last line for a 'DirectoryResetAttributes' method and use delete separately.

On a related note, while this worked, I then had issues with deleting paths that were 'too long' and ended up using a robocopy solution posted here: [C# deleting a folder that has long paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223007/c-sharp-deleting-a-folder-that-has-long-paths/)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Vitaliy Ulantikov's solution I have supplemented it with a rename/move folder method:

```
  public static void renameFolder(String sourcePath, String targetPath) {
     try
     {
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
           DeleteFileSystemInfo(new DirectoryInfo(targetPath));
        System.IO.Directory.Move(sourcePath, targetPath);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("renameFolder: " + sourcePath + " " + targetPath + " " + ex.Message);
        throw ex;
     }
  }

  private static void DeleteFileSystemInfo(FileSystemInfo fsi) {
     fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
     var di = fsi as DirectoryInfo;

     if (di != null)
     {
        foreach (var dirInfo in di.GetFileSystemInfos())
        {
           DeleteFileSystemInfo(dirInfo);
        }
     }

     fsi.Delete();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for NET framework 3.5 and for NET framework version 4 and higher:

```
#region DeleteWithReadOnly
internal static void DeleteWithReadOnly(this DirectoryInfo di)
{
   foreach (FileSystemInfo fsi in di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
   {
      fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
   }
   di.Delete(true);
}
#endregion

#region DeleteWithReadOnlyNET3_5
internal static void DeleteWithReadOnlyNET3_5(this DirectoryInfo di)
{
   foreach (FileSystemInfo fsi in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
   {
      fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
   }
   di.Delete(true);
}
#endregion
```

Usage:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TMP");
di.DeleteWithReadOnly();
```