# C#. How to delete git folder?

Tags: c#

My C# code call git and cloning repository, but when my program ends i need to delete this folder with clone repo inside.
When i use

```
Directory.Delete(path, true)
```

All files are deleted except .git and when program trying to delete .git -

```
"Access to the path 'pack-3241a6c3ea7ff447e5ba864f5d87ef66c5913670.idx' is denied."
```

I tried

> [Directory.Delete doesn't work. Access denied error but under Windows Explorer it's ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701457/directory-delete-doesnt-work-access-denied-error-but-under-windows-explorer-it)

But it won't help.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Is it possible that the git process you launched is still running?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have commented out all lines except deleting

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe show a little more code. Also, you may have a crashed git.exe launched by a previous debugging session that is still alive.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i have only Directory.Delete(@"C:/Test", true) in my code now. git.exe not launched and i have admin rights. I can delete it in explorer without problems

Comment: `Directory.Delete` will not delete read-only files.

Answer (score 7):

> when clone source from gitlab, in that folder will contain files is readonly and hidden. So if you use Directory.delete() file is read only and hidden can not delete before, folder will no delete.
> To delete it, you should find all file(read only, hidden, ...) in the directory, and then set attribute is normal. now you can delete all file and then is folder.

> "path" you should use **"<disk>:\<yourfoler>\"** format. example: "C:\gitlab\"

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path) { Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal };

foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
}

directory.Delete(true);
```