# deleting a file generates Exception "could not find a part of the path"

Tags: c#, .net, file, delete-file

I want to delete a Directory and all its files and it has files/Directories with a very long path.

The file I'm trying to delete has a long path (longer than 260 characters).

How can I delete this file in spite of its length?
I'm using the following code:

```
foreach (string archiveFolder in Archives)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime creationTime = Directory.GetCreationTime(archiveFolder);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime passDate = creationTime.AddDays(numDaysBack);
        if (passDate.CompareTo(now) < 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(archiveFolder, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            //System.Console.WriteLine(creationTime);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Managed code can't deal with paths longer than 260 AFAIK... IIRC the only option would be to call native Windows API via pinvoke...

Comment: Also, is this your real code? If so, then you shouldn't be ignoring exceptions. You'd do better to just remove the try/catch blocks entirely.

Comment: [Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows) contains useful information

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223007/c-sharp-deleting-a-folder-that-has-long-paths

Comment: Is it the target directory's name that's too long or the hole path ? Can you edit your question and add an example of `archiveFolder` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# deleting a folder that has long paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223007/c-sharp-deleting-a-folder-that-has-long-paths)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem of having a file with long path down inside the directory structure of the directory I'm deleting by prepending `\\?\` (long path specifier) to the Directory.Delete argument.

So in your cause it would be

```cs
   Directory.Delete(@"\\?\" + archiveFolder, true);
```

Comment: For the record, it appears this results in an exception about invalid characters in the path, at least on .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 1):

[Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx) is meant to delete directories, to delete files use [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

They both reside in `System.IO`, the change should be trivial.

Comment: I want to delete a Directory and all its files and it has files/Directories with a very long path