# File.Delete Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, file

My console application program is creating some runtime files while it is working so what I want to do is delete all of these files on the application startup. I have tried this:

```
public static void Empty(string targetDir)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(targetDir);
    if (!directory.Exists) return;
    foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles()) file.Delete();
    foreach (var subDirectory in directory.GetDirectories()) subDirectory.Delete(true);
}
```

...just to look for all the files/folders in the given path (which is in a subdirectory in the program execution path) then delete them. However, I get the following exception:

> Access to the path 'file' is denied.

I tried to run the program as administrator with no luck; However, I want a solution that works without using administrator privileges.

Notes :

1. The file is not running in another application.
2. The file is not in a protected folder.
3. The file can be deleted manually with no problems and that's why i
   am here.

Comment: Just a doubt: Are you really deleting all files in the application path?

Comment: I just want to say that because your program is also a file.

Comment: Ofc No, the files i am deleting are in a subdirectory located in the app path.

Comment: What is the actual value the error message gives? You've substituted `'file'` there..

Comment: yes, see which one is complaining, that should be easy to trace - there could be couple things. Also try deleting that file manually etc. You have a very clear case for debugging

Comment: do you load some dll's or use streams?

Comment: it is deleted manually with no probs.

Comment: just an assumption, can you create a list of files outside of foreach and loop through it?

Comment: @VladL : i don't get what you mean.

Comment: FileInfo[] fi = directory.GetFiles(); foreach(var file in fi) file.Delete(); and same for directory. Maybe enumarator causes the problem

Comment: @VladL: Exception is not about collections, it's I/O

Comment: @Xaqron really? :D actually what I assume is that GetFiles() returns Ienumerable, which is created by yielded return, which could cause problems if one or more files are missing after the first remove

Comment: @VladL you are thinking of "InvalidOperationException - collection was modified" but in this case there is an "access denied"

Comment: Alternative answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/648055/3543437

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a directory with read-only files in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611921/how-do-i-delete-a-directory-with-read-only-files-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem` methods as it has a handy `DeleteDirectory` method, I had access troubles awhile ago and this was the fix for my problem.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(targetDir);
if (directory.Exists)
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(targetDir, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents);
}
```

Comment: ehm is this exists in .Net 2 ?

Comment: First i think this is a visual basic code also, i can't find this in .Net 2

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletedirectory(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You will have to add the reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Answer (score 14):

I got this error and found that it was because my test files were readonly. Changed this and I can now use fileinfo to delete them no worries.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal);
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Answer (score 4):

You say that the files are not open in another application, but it must be open within your application:

```
//Create some directories to delete
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/DeleteMe");
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/DeleteMe/DeleteMe");
File.Create("C:/Temp/DeleteMe/DeleteMeFile");//FileStream still open!!

//Delete the files
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Temp/DeleteMe");
if (!directory.Exists) return;
foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directory.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true);
}
```

Make sure you dispose the file stream when you create the file

```
//Create some directories to delete
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/DeleteMe");
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Temp/DeleteMe/DeleteMe");
using (File.Create("C:/Temp/DeleteMe/DeleteMeFile")) { }

//Delete the files
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Temp/DeleteMe");
if (!directory.Exists) return;
foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directory.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows API MoveFileEx might be a potential solution with a parameter MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT to remove the file only after reboot.

Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: Eventually the easiest way it would be to call native code, from C#. A quick search shows a nice example that will certainly cheer you up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077869/movefile-function-in-c-sharp-delete-file-after-reboot-c-sharp