# Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I have a C# desktop app.

I am using the Process class to convert images to a video file by using FFMPEG.

This is my code:

```
using (Process serverBuild = new Process())
{
    serverBuild.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string args = " -f image2  -i " + {path} + "\\img%05d.jpg -s 352x288  -filter:v \"setpts=5.0*PTS\" -y " + {path}\\File.mp4;

    serverBuild.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    serverBuild.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
    serverBuild.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    serverBuild.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    serverBuild.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    serverBuild.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    serverBuild.Start();
    //  string output = serverBuild.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    //Log.Instance.Debug(serverBuild.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
    serverBuild.WaitForExit();
    serverBuild.Close();

}

 Directory.Delete(ExportRoute + FFMPEGPacket.LicenseKey + "\\" + FFMPEGPacket.Guid, true);

//which raise the error..
```

The images are all deleted but the File.Mp4 is not and that is the error. The error says that the newly created MP4 file cannot be deleted.

NB
This is partial code to illustrate the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following code to create the file (it worked for me):

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = exe_path;
        // replace your arguments here
        psi.Arguments = string.Format(@" arguments ") 

        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.ErrorDialog = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi);
        exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
        string outString = string.Empty;
        exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            outString += e.Data;
        };
        exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        string errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Trace.WriteLine(outString);
        Trace.TraceError(errString);
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        exeProcess.Close();
        exeProcess.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I will check it out as soon as i can. thanks

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG might still be rendering the creation of video from images after it closes, so it might be worth if you place a Threading.Thead.Sleep(5000) 5 secs; before delete.

Comment: Hi, well the 'WaitForExit' should work but I have already added Thread.Sleep(10000); to my code and still did not work. What a pain!

Comment: Well, btw what's your objective in this one? Do you intend to delete whole folder? if not, why not delete each file except File.Mp4?

Comment: my objective is to delete the whole folder

Comment: Wooh, this is tough. If your app closes (without delete at the end). Can the folder be manually deleted?

Comment: HI, yes it can. So, FFMPEG must be locking it for some reason. I am disposing my Process so cannot see what is holding it..

Comment: So this can be solved via serverBuild.Dispose(); before Delete directory. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I should not have to though as the 'using' statement does it for me

Comment: Could you expain how using 'using' solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]);
File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: Sorry, a different error: Access to the path 'd:\Cloud\Exports\EC462-4B771-B1DCC-D5730\33e50f75-0ec8-4bec-ad27-7025d6502dcd' is denied.

Comment: What about trying it inside using(File.Create(path)) block?

Comment: on :  File.WriteAllBytes(ExportRoute + FFMPEGPacket.LicenseKey + "\\" + FFMPEGPacket.Guid, new byte[0]);

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting? Why would I want to create a directory? I am trying to delete the file?

Comment: I thought taking over the usage rights of the file etc. Lastly did you look at here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260146/file-delete-access-to-the-path-is-denied)