# File.Delete Access to the path is denied for XLS/XLSX files in C#

Tags: c#, .net

My WPF application cannot delete an XLS/XLSX file.

```
File.Delete("D:\\Temp\\Test1\\file123.xlsx");
```

Generates this error, [Access to the path is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekpy.png)

- The file was created in Excel. File is not open in Excel when I am trying this, because I know if the file was open in Excel then that can cause this error.
- File's Properties were changed to provide Full Control Read/Write access to Users using Windows Explorer
- I can delete the file in Windows Explorer

If the file extension is changed to something else, like 'txt' or 'ddt' then File.Delete() works.

I also tried changing the file's attribute,

```
File.SetAttributes("D:\\Temp\\Test1\\file123.xlsx", FileAttributes.Normal);
```

but this gave the same error.

[I also tried to use the Visual Basic's DeleteFile suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15260480/13562420)
and this did not work

How do I fix this 'Access to the path is denied' error?

Visual Studio Professional 2022. WPF .NET 6.0,
Windows 11 Professional

Comment: Is D: a local drive or a Network Drive?

Comment: although it might sound weird, try to rename the file before you delete it. rename test.xlsm to 1.txt and try to delete it.

Comment: Try fully closing Excel. Sometimes it can keep file handles open longer.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock D: is a local drive.

Comment: @Mahobo: Yes, renaming does work. I changed the name from 'file123.xlsx' to 'file123.txt', then I could delete it.

Comment: @Charlieface Excel was fully closed, I did not any instance of Excel open.

Comment: @arvdev, I moved my comment to an answer as it seemed to help you here.

Comment: Typical anti-malware induced mishap.  They do treat Office files specially, that's why renaming the file seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

One cause for access deinied for some files like ".txt",".xlsx" or ... is that

1. **the file is open in your computer, assure that the file is close at first.**
2. **Try run your application as an adminstrator.**

Comment: I did try running Microsoft Studio as an Admin and went into debug mode, but still got the same error

Comment: Try to give some permissions to the folder and exe

Answer (score 0):

As this helped the opener,I put it in as an answer instead of comment.

although it might sound weird, try to rename the file before you delete it. rename test.xlsm to 1.txt and try to delete it.

Comment: I was able to rename in Windows Explorer, and then delete it using 'File.Delete()'. Originally I did try to rename it in my code using 'File.Move("C:\\Temp\\File123.xlsx", "C:\\Temp\\FileTxt123.txt");', but this gave the same 'Access is denied' error

Answer (score 0):

@HansPassant was right. It was caused by my anti-malware tool. So issue is solved, and `File.Delete("C:\\Temp\\File123.xlsx");` deletes the file. I just had to tell my anti-malware to trust my application.

When I used Windows Explorer to rename the file from File123.xlsx to FileTxt123.txt, then `File.Delete("C:\\Temp\\File123.xlsx");` worked, and the anti-malware did not cause any issues. So the anti-malware only has issues with accessing Excel files in code.