# Access denied - Trying to delete all files in a folder

Tags: c#, directory, access-denied, delete-file

I'm currently trying to **delete** all **files** in a folder **(Recently opened files)**, but without any luck, I get the message: **"Access to the path 'C:\Users\User\Recent' is denied."** . I've been looking around to see if there were any solutions, but unfortunately I can't find anything.

[image: Image:]

```
String recent = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%") + "\\Recent";
                        EmptyFolderContents(recent);

    private void EmptyFolderContents(string folderName)
        {

            foreach (var Folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(Folder, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            foreach (var Files in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
            {
                try
                {
                   File.Delete(Files);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the Access Denied error is because you can't just delete files from that folder. They are virtual paths to real files. There is probably a better way to do what you are doing.

Here is an alternative that I found [here](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_clear_recent_documents). It uses WinAPI, which is never fun, but it works.

```
//you'll need to add this.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern void SHAddToRecentDocs(ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags flag, IntPtr pidl);

public enum ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags
{
    Pidl = 0x001,
    Path = 0x002,
}

//then call this from your method
SHAddToRecentDocs(ShellAddToRecentDocsFlags.Pidl, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Where is the string parameter which represents the folder or file to delete?

Comment: @LeiYang It just clears the recent documents. It does not delete a specific entry.

Comment: If you don't want to go the WinAPI route, check out this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/648055/3543437

Comment: Thankx Gray! Your answer is very usefull to me, thankx again

Answer (score 1):

Your error message seems to show that you're missing a backslash:

Access to the path 'C:Users\User\Recent' is denied.

(after the C:)

Comment: A thought -- In Windows you can't delete a file if it is open in some application (or a folder containing such a file).

Answer (score 0):

I Use Permissions Time Machine v1.1 to restore default permissions and remove "Access is denied" message for folder or files or registry keys or windows services or wmi objects it's free and fast and easy

download it from amyd projects blog