# xunit 2.0 - run code before and after all tests

Tags: xunit

Now when Xunit 2.0 is release what is the possibility to run setup/tear down code before and after ALL tests are run?
It was not possible in Xunit 1 but according to this [xUnit.net - run code once before and after ALL tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829737/xunit-run-code-before-and-after-all-tests) there were plans to support that behavior in 2.0.

Comment: See the accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33778396/1904753 for a good example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like in your case, Collection Fixtures could be helpful. You can find an [example](http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#collection-fixture) in xUnit documentation. In this example, a constructor and a Dispose method of the DatabaseFixture class are places where you can write setup / tear down code. Create a base class for your tests and use this collection fixture for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the AssemblyFixture example published by xUnit, which shows how you can get assembly-level setup and cleanup: https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/AssemblyFixtureExample