# Is there a way to mimic the function of startup.cs in unit test cases while running multiple tests together?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I am trying to test some code that uses a static class. The static class has a initialization method which can be called only once and throws exception if called second time.  I have multiple test cases which tests the code that need to access the static class. In the code the initialization is done in startup.cs. How do I do something similar for test cases. I am using x-unit for unit testing.

```
 public static class UniqueId
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (_generator != null)
            throw new Exception("Already initialized.");
        _generator = new IdGenerator();
    }


    private static IdGenerator _generator = null;
    
    public static BigId NextId()
    {
        if (_generator == null)
            throw new Exception("Not initialized.");
        return _generator.NextId();
    }
}
```

Code that I want to test:

```
public string GenerateId
{
    return UniqueId.NextId().ToString()
}
```

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: I am using x-unit

Comment: [Run code once before and after ALL tests in xUnit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829737/run-code-once-before-and-after-all-tests-in-xunit-net) has an interesting answer, although it seems to only be available in newer versions of xUnit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143426/5803406

Comment: @devNull That was helpful. Solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you need to set your class to implement the IDisposible and just call Dispose() when you want to destroy it.

Here a example:

```
namespace Prime.UnitTests.Services
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class YourClassTest
    {

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            //some configs...
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test_size_String_1()
        {
            UniqueId.Initialize();
            Assert.IsFalse(UniqueId.NextId().ToString() == 10); // quick example...
            UniqueId.Dispose();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test_size_String_2XPTO()
        {
            UniqueId.Initialize();
            Assert.IsFalse(UniqueId.NextId().ToString() == 115); // quick example...
            UniqueId.Dispose();
        }

    }
}


public static class UniqueId : IDisposable  
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (_generator != null)
            throw new Exception("Already initialized.");
        _generator = new IdGenerator();
    }


    private static IdGenerator _generator = null;
    
    public static BigId NextId()
    {
        if (_generator == null)
            throw new Exception("Not initialized.");
        return c.NextId();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _generator?.Dispose(); //Depends of the context of your IdGenerator
        //or
        _generator == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using X-Unit

Comment: Also IdGenerator is an internal class. So I can't directly mock that in test cases

Comment: here, just follow that, izi pizi :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: I'll edit my solution so you test it :)

Comment: So, I edited the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood, in [**`MSTest`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-members-in-unit-tests?view=vs-2019), look into `[TestInitialize]`, `[ClassInitialize]` (likely what you need) and see if either works for your use case for a "startup" function

`[TestInitialize]`

- runs before all your unit tests (each)

[`[ClassInitialize]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms245248(v=vs.120)#remarks)

- runs once, the only official doc I can find these days is older...

> ## ClassInitializeAttribute Class
>
> Identifies a method that contains code that must be used before any of
> the tests in the test class have run and to allocate resources to be
> used by the test class. This class cannot be inherited.
>
> ### Remarks
>
> When run in a load test, the method marked with this attribute
> will run once, and any initialization operations it performs will
> apply to the entire test. If you need to do initialization operations
> once for every virtual user iteration in the test, use the
> TestInitializeAttribute.
>
> The order that methods will be run is:
>
> 1. Methods marked with the `AssemblyInitializeAttribute`.
> 2. Methods marked with the `ClassInitializeAttribute`.
> 3. Methods marked with the `TestInitializeAttribute`.
> 4. Methods marked with the `TestMethodAttribute`.
>
> Only one method in a class may be decorated with this attribute.
>
> #### Important
>
> *This attribute should not be used on ASP.NET unit tests, that is, any
> test with [HostType("ASP.NET")] attribute. Because of the stateless
> nature of IIS and ASP.NET, a method decorated with this attribute may
> be called more than once per test run.*

Hth

Answer (score -2):

It depends on which test framework you're using.

EDIT: I see now that you're using xUnit, but I'll leave the entire answer in case it's helpful to someone else.

**xUnit**

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590641/12431728), which talks about how to create a global setup/teardown for a set of tests. To sum up that answer, if you create a constructor for your unit test class in Xunit, that method will be called before each test method. It also states:

> A more optimized version would use the IClassFixture interface to
> ensure that the global initialization/teardown functionality is only
> called once. For this version, you don't extends a base class from
> your test class but implement the IClassFixture interface where T
> refers to your fixture class:
>
> ```c#
> using Xunit;
>
> public class TestsFixture : IDisposable {
>     public TestsFixture ()
>     {
>         // Do "global" initialization here; Only called once.
>     }
>
>     public void Dispose()
>     {
>         // Do "global" teardown here; Only called once.
>     } }
>
> public class DummyTests : IClassFixture<TestsFixture> {
>     public DummyTests(TestsFixture data)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This will result in the constructor of TestsFixture only being run
> once for every class under test. It thus depends on what you want
> exactly to choose between the two methods.

If you're using **NUnit** it already has a `OneTimeSetUp` attribute you can use ([docs here](http://nunitsoftware.com/nunitv2/index.php?p=onetimeSetUp&r=2.6.6)), like this:

```c#
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        // Initialize things here; only called once
    }
}
```

If you're using something other than xUnit and NUnit, check the documentation for the framework you use, and look for a one-time setup.