# How to start code before all tests in XUnit?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, xunit

I need to run the code before running my xUnit tests. Do it once and that's it. Is it possible, for example, as beforeAll in Jest?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829737/run-code-once-before-and-after-all-tests-in-xunit-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xUnit.net: Global setup + teardown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown)