# run initialisation and teardown code once while outputting in the constructor and destructor

Tags: c#, xunit

In **xUnit** I need to run some code **once**, before any test is executed, and also some code after all tests are done. Although this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown) explains how to do it quite well, I want to do some printing inside the constructor and destructor, like shown in the code below, and that's the tricky part. Since `Console.Writeline` won't work, I looked for a workaround, which I found in this [link](http://n-develop.com/console-writeline-in-xunit-tests/).

```
public class TestsFixture : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public TestsFixture(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;

        // Do "global" initialization here; Only called once.
        _output.WriteLine("global init");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do "global" teardown here; Only called once.
        _output.WriteLine("global teardown");
    }
} 

public class HandlerTests : IClassFixture<TestsFixture>
{
    // All my tests are here
}
```

A brief explanation on what's going on here:

> This code uses the IUseFixture interface to ensure that the global
>   initialization/teardown functionality is only called once. For this
>   version, you don't extend a base class from your test class but
>   implement the IUseFixture interface where T refers to your fixture
>   class

Everything seems fine, but when I run the tests, I get an error (below). Any idea on how to solve this problem?

> ```
> Test Outcome: Failed
> Test Duration:    0:00:00,001
>
> Result Message:   Class fixture type 'TestsPlatform.TestsFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: ITestOutputHelper output
> ```

Comment: How do you create an instance of TestsFixture?

Comment: @Valentin That is not done by me, but within IClassFixture. I added some more information to the question. Nonetheless, if I remove the printing the test is executed successfully, so I don't believe that to be the problem

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html) says that you can add a parameter of type `ITestOutputHelper` to the constructor of the **test** class. I don't see anything that says you can add it as a parameter to the constructor of a **test fixture** class...

It wouldn't make sense for this output to go via `ITestOutputHelper` because the whole point of that mechanism is to allow the output to be associated with a specific test. Your setup/teardown is global, not per-test.

You'll need to find another way to output those diagnostics.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much for your explanation! Do you know about such a way?

Comment: @rsy: not offhand, no - and I guess it depends on where you want the output to appear. Are you sure that `Console.WriteLine` won't work? I know that's no longer written to the test results, but maybe it's still written to the output? If not, try using a `TraceListener` (from `System.Diagnostics`) and doing `Trace.Write...`.

Comment: It is not outputted to the output. I'll read about the TraceListener. Thank you again!