# xUnit Testing says System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

Good day,

I'm begginer in xUnit and I'm facing this error that says, "`System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`"

Here's my code where it tests whether a rulename depending on the season.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private CalculateDiscount calculateDiscount;

    [Fact]
    public void Setup()
    {
        calculateDiscount = new CalculateDiscount();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(10.00, "Summer", 100.00)]
    public void WhenRuleName_Is_Summer_Return_Valid(decimal amount, string ruleName, decimal expected)
    {
        var result = calculateDiscount.CalculateDiscountSalary(amount, ruleName);

        Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    }
}
```

And here is my actual implementation

```
public class CalculateDiscount
{
    public decimal CalculateDiscountSalary(decimal amount, string ruleName)
    {
        if (ruleName.Equals("Summer"))
        {
            return amount * 10.00M;
        }
        else if (ruleName.Equals("Winter"))
        {
            return amount * 15.00M;
        }
        else
        {
            return amount * 20.00M;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the error being thrown. I already know but want to see if you can learn how to debug from this process. What have you tried so far in trying to solve your problem?

Comment: In the test method itself. The `WhenRuleName_Is_Summer_Return_Valid` sir

Comment: Great, and what could possibly be null in that method? and why? Learn to step through your code.

Comment: I'm trying to put a breakpoint on the `{` of this method but it doesn't break sir

Comment: Put the break point on the line with `var`

Comment: It doesn't even break there sir

Comment: Oh I use the `Debug Selected Test` sir but the `calculateDiscount` is null. All the parameters have a value though

Comment: When the break point hits, check the state of the variables at that point

Comment: That is correct. Now why would it be null based on what you have in the test?

Comment: Thank you sir. I just needed to put in on my constructor instead

Comment: Sigh...yes. Wanted you to come to that conclusion yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact do not have to run before Theory.

Your setup must be your constructor. If you change your setup function as constructor, your null reference exception problem is resolved

```
public UnitTest1()
{
    calculateDiscount = new CalculateDiscount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused with XUnit and NUnit.

NUnit provides a `SetUp` Fixture to initialize variables that you can use repeatedly.

As of the moment, XUnit doesn't have. But there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown).