# .Net Core Entity Framework core, using new database for each test in same test class

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a few tests to test the patching functionality. I am using this custom factory
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples/2.x/IntegrationTestsSample/tests/RazorPagesProject.Tests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs

For each test, I want to create new database or at-least clear and seed data again. Because other tests are messing up with data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

This ensures that the database for the context does not exist. If it does not exist, no action is taken. If it does exist then the database is deleted.

Comment: yeah I saw that somewhere, but not sure where exactly to use that.

Comment: In the factory mentioned above on line 44 - right before EnsureCreated()

Comment: yeah but that only runs once in the scope, when I run all tests in one file, it's under single scope, so test share the context and hence same data

Comment: Use IClassFixture<T> - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown)...