# Save current state and revert it after running tests with xUnit

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, xunit.net

I created some tests for my SetDesktopWallpaper() static method with xUnit.
As its name implies, it changes the current users's desktop wallpaper.

Here is one of my tests.

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(@".\Resources\JpgWallpaper.jpg")]
[InlineData(@".\Resources\PngWallpaper.png")]
public void Changing_Wallpaper_File_Should_Work(string value)
{
    const string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop";
    const string keyVal1 = "WallPaper";

    WallChanger.SetDesktopWallpaper(value);

    Assert.Equal(Path.GetFullPath(value), Registry.GetValue(keyName, keyVal1, null).ToString());
}
```

I would like it to save the current wallpaper at the beginning of the tests and put it back at the end.
How to achieve this with xUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the context provided, I would implement `IDisposable` interface in your test class, save the info you want to restore in the constructor and, following [dispose pattern implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1063?view=vs-2019); having it restored at the end of every test case.

You also have [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41985831/5459321) using collection fixtures, but that's for more general setup/teardown, so I don't think it's the way to go in your case.

Both alternatives are described in more detail [here](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.html).