# How to use ICollectionFixture with CollectionPerAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have this setup:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(CollectionBehavior.CollectionPerAssembly, DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

I want to use `ICollectionFixture<T>` to share an instance to the whole assembly.

It seems that I have to declare a `[CollectionDefinition]` class to use  `ICollectionFixture` but how can I do it if I use the `CollectionPerAssembly` approach?

```
[CollectionDefinition("???")]
class Definition : ICollectionFixture<MySingleton>
{

}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown

Answer (score 1):

While the naming suggests there is an overlap, this is not the case.

You need to either:

a) have a `CollectionDefinition`, with every Test Class marked as part of that `Collection`, and be passed a ref to it via the ctor
b) create and access a singleton out of band and/or do prep with a [C# 9 *module initializer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#support-for-code-generators)