# Run lines of code before each test in Xunit c#

Tags: ui-automation, xunit.net

I want to run some lines of code before each test in Xunit, how to do this set up.
Already tried using set up but that is for Nunit

Comment: put it in the the constructor for the Test Class - in xUnit, an instance is created per individual test run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xUnit.net: Global setup + teardown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown)

Answer (score 2):

xUnit has a good [documentation page](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) where describes 3 methods to solve this problem. If you want just run a setup/cleanup code, use constructor and Dispose() method. xUnit creates a new instance of the test class for every test that is run. Below is the example from docs:

```
public class StackTests : IDisposable
{
    Stack<int> stack;

    public StackTests()
    {
        stack = new Stack<int>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stack.Dispose();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WithNoItems_CountShouldReturnZero()
    {
        var count = stack.Count;
        Assert.Equal(0, count);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AfterPushingItem_CountShouldReturnOne()
    {
        stack.Push(42);
        var count = stack.Count;
        Assert.Equal(1, count);
    }
}
```