# Method to be called before any test (xUnit)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, xunit

Is there any way to create method that will be automatically called before any test?

```
[Fact]
public void Test1() { }

[Fact]
public void Test2() { }

private void Prepare()
{
    // Prepare test environment
}
```

I need `Prepare` to be called before `Test1` and `Test2`. It should be like this:

1. Call `Prepare()`
2. Call `Test1`
3. Call `Prepare()`
4. Call `Test2`

I know that i can call it by my own like

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    Prepare();
}
```

but is there any way to do it **automatically**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xUnit.net: Global setup + teardown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976319/xunit-net-global-setup-teardown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include that call to the `Prepare` method in the constructor of your test class.

The [documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons) comparing other testing frameworks that have e.g. a `[SetUp]` attribute or alike mentions below.

> We believe that use of `[SetUp]` is generally bad. However, you can implement a parameterless constructor as a direct replacement.

Comment: That does not work if the setup has async code

Comment: @DavidThielen That's true. In case you would need an async setup, than have a look at xUnit's `IAsyncLifetime` interface having an `Task InitializeAsync` method. That's rather out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could call *Prepare* method in the construtor of the class. So it will be called automatically before tests methods.

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public ClassTest()
    {
        Prepare();
    }
    public void Prepare()
    {
        // your logic
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange
       
       //Act

       //Assert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *NUnit* there is an [*SetUp* attribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setup.html) that you can use for a method, that should be run before any test.

In *xUnit* it seems like, that you need to create this by yourself ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590641/8323477))