# How can I pass a parameter to the interface IClassFixture<TFixture>?

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I am writing a unit test using xUnit for .Net core.

Below is the TestBase Class

```
public class TestBase : IDisposable
{
    TestBase(string filename) {
        ...
        stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filename))));
    }
    public TestBase() : this("filename.csv") { }            

    public void Dispose() {
        ..
    }
}
```

Here's how it's being used

```
public class FileProcessingServiceFacadeTest : IClassFixture<TestBase>
{
    TestBase testBase { get; set; }

    public FileProcessingServiceFacadeTest(TestBase testBase) {
        this.testBase = testBase;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ProcessAsync() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Because I don't know how to pass the parameter to the TestBase class using **interface IClassFixture**, I had to create a constructor that internally calls the parameter constructor.

Can I pass a parameter to **interface IClassFixture** without an additional constructor?

Comment: Removed the `#region`s - please don't do that on either SO or in real life; they add nothing and are a code smell.

Comment: Is it possible you're looking at tutorials targeted at xUnit 1.x ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175366/11635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only default constructors are supported for Class (or Collection Fixtures). The main use cases are [covered in the docs](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context).

The interface is solely a marker which the test runner uses to know what it needs to create/dispose for a given Test Class. If the constructor on the Test Class asks for the instances, it gets them supplied; if not, that's fine too (they still get created and Disposed)

In other words, the best you can do is to define a base class and then have a concrete derived class that passes down the filename.