# Directory.Delete(path, true) always gives error - ASP.NET 3.5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory, .net-3.5

I'm using MVC ASP.NET 3.5 and I'm trying to delete a folder with all files within using standard .NET method that I've always used in .NET 2.0.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true) but the first answer doesn't seem to work.
I've tried this one

```
try
{
    Directory.Delete(path, true);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    Thread.Sleep(0);
    Directory.Delete(path, true);
}
```

and works, but I can't understand why.
Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I've got permissions, because all files and sub-folders were deleted. But I've got and Exception "Directory is non-empty" with path. If I use the code provided, works without any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even using the explorer this message is shown sometimes (at least for me). How about deleting the files first and then delete the folder?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(some_path, "", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string pathFile in files)
{
    File.Delete(pathFile);
}
Directory.Delete(some_path);
```

you can use SearchOptions if you have subfolers but if not, then use simply

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(some_path);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

This problem happens for many reasons(c'mon its MS), but I think the main are: because the folder is corrupted or some process is locking it and prevents the deletion.

A non elegant solution could be: delete the files first, then the subfolders, and the last step delete the main folder.

Comment: Your approach works, but the problem is that if you have subfolders, you have to delete them. Also, still doesn't explain the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this it worked for me

```
  File.SetAttributes(DownloaddirPath & "\" & directoryName, FileAttributes.Normal)
  Directory.Delete(DownloaddirPath & "\" & directoryName, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough permissions to delete the folder? Also, as the other question says make sure that the directory is empty.

Comment: I've got permissions, because all files and sub-folders were deleted. But I've got and Exception "Directory is non-empty" with path.
If I use the code provided, works without any exceptions.