# Creating Then Deleting File Causes IOException

Tags: c#, .net

An application needs to create a file in a directory, do something in the directory, and then delete the file. For example, the source code below:

```
File.Create("textfile.txt");
// Do something here
File.Delete("textfile.txt");
```

If "something" is a process that only needs a very short amount of time, File.Delete will throw IOException (file is being used by another process). According to another SO post: [Cannot delete directory with Directory.Delete(path, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true), calling Thread.Sleep(0) should allow the previous process to finish. However, even with

```
File.Create("textfile.txt");
// Do something here
Thread.Sleep(0);
File.Delete("textfile.txt");
```

the same IOException is still be thrown.

The solution I got is a while-loop that try to delete the file repeatedly until it's deleted. But I'm wondering if theres' a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answers (and pointing out it's on MSDN. I'm certainly not feeling very bright right now). Gonna go with @usr because he's the first. But please accept the +1 as my thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`File.Create` returns you a FileStream which represents an open handle to that file. Wrap the result of that call in a using-block to close the handle deterministically.

Answer (score 21):

The [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) method will create a file-stream, which you will need to dispose of correctly. I suggest the following code:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Create("textfile.txt"))
{
    // Do something here.
}
File.Delete("textfile.txt");
```

Note that this code is exactly as suggested in the MSDN documentation...

Answer (score 4):

Also note: If you do not want to write anything into the file, you can avoid the "using" in two ways:

```
(1) File.WriteAllText("textfile.txt", string.Empty);
(2) File.Create("textfile.txt").Dispose();
```

In case (2) it is safe to avoid the using because you are doing nothing that could throw an exception between creating it and disposing it.

Answer (score 3):

File.Create returns a FileStream which is an open handle to that file. Use this instead:

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Create("textfile.txt"))
{}

File.Delete("textfile.txt");
```