# Delete folder with C# code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a folder but i can manage to get it right?

The folder i am trying to delete is called **ExtractedFiles** and it is inside a folder called **FormValue**.

I can delete a spreadsheet in the same **FormValue** folder but cant delete the folder.

I think the problem might be that i don't have the right file extension for the folder

This works:

```
if (File.Exists(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xls"))
            {
                File.Delete(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xls");
            }
```

This does not work:

```
 if (File.Exists(tempFolderPathAlt + "ExtractedFiles"))
            {
                File.Delete(tempFolderPathAlt + "ExtractedFiles");
            }
```

Could someone please tell me the file extension of a folder or how to delete one?

Comment: if you need to delete the Folder and all its content why don't you use Directory.Delete ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

Comment: Use `Path.Combine()` for combining paths

Comment: I think you need Directory.Delete, not File.Delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to delete a folder, you should use [`Directory.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx) instead of `File.Delete`:

```
String path = Path.Combine(tempFolderPathAlt, "ExtractedFiles");
bool directoryExists = Directory.Exists(path);
if(directoryExists)
    Directory.Delete(path, true); // deletes sub-directories
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

you want

```
Directory.Delete
```

Since your deleting a folder and not a file

Answer (score 0):

For deleting dirrectories, you need to use the method

```
Directory.Delete(string path,
    bool recursive);
```

Refer official docs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you are getting IOException deleting directories :

[Cannot delete directory with Directory.Delete(path, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true)