# How to delete everything in a folder with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, io, directory

I need a function to clear the entire content of a folder. `ASP.Net` cannot delete folders if the folder is not empty.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/329355/497356

Comment: Are any of the files in use? That could screw things up... I'm guessing that with all the solutions shown below, you're going to need some exception handling!

Comment: -1 for asking a question that is fairly well covered already, and then answering it immediately yourself.

Comment: Either you really don't know how to use google, or you are trying to up your own rep by answering your own question.

Comment: I just wanted to share idea of looping in files and folders. I m not pursuing reputation, (I only got 182 points in ~2 years). hopefully a moderator will delete the topic and no one else will waste their time no more..

Answer (score 3):

You can use DirectoryInfo, [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts.aspx) method with parameter specifying whether to delete subdirectories and files :

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\path");
if (di.Exists)
  di.Delete(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar today.

Try this:

```
foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories("C:\path"))
{
   Directory.Delete(folder, true);
}
```

The 'true' is for recursive. So that all subitems (files and folders) will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fxeahc5f.aspx), where the *second* parameter specifies:

```
public static void Delete(
    string path,
    bool recursive
)
```

> recursive Type: System.Boolean true to remove directories,
>   subdirectories, and files in path; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I came up with to erase files in the folder first, and then the folder itself:

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\path");
    foreach (string folder in folders){
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (string file in files){
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        Directory.Delete(folder);
    }
```