# I copied a file with C#. Now I can't delete it?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, directory

I copied some directories/files with a procedure on C#.
Now, I'd like to remove the main directory.

So this is the basic code:

```
dir.Delete(true);
```

but I reckon a `UnauthorizedAccessException` (access to directories.acrodata, which is a file, denied).

Why? How can I force it?

Comment: are an application running with administrator privileges?

Comment: There may be an object in your application that is still holding on to the main directory and thus not allowing it to be deleted.

Comment: Does your C# app have delete permissions on the directory?

Comment: "play" on visual studio :) Dunno if it works with admin privileges :O

Comment: Yes I can delete all files, but it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should dispose any handles you have to a file from the ones you want to delete. Then you can use the following code to ensure that read only files get deleted, too:

```
public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        DeleteDirectory(dir);
    }

    Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
}
```

Source and more info in [this Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true/329502#329502).

Comment: Well, I have an empty folder, which is read-only. How can I remove that attributes from a directory?

Comment: Try using the Attributes property of the DirectoryInfo class, for example:  `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);  di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;`

Answer (score 6):

You probably either 1) limited security privileges there and are unable to delete a file or 2) have a handle to a file or directory still open (in use) which is preventing you from deleting.

```
Directory.Delete(string);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3.aspx

> UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> The caller does not have the required permission.

Comment: Depends on how you copied.  For instance, always put your streams in a Using so that they automatically close and dispose afterwards: using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) { /* ... */ }

Comment: Also, as Pavel Vladov and smhnkmr noted careful of ReadOnly attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The Directory you are trying to delete may be ReadOnly. So setting the ReadOnly attribute to false and deleting the same would work.

e.g:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("SomeFolder");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessing that after your copy operation, you failed to properly close Streams meaning that you're still holding a handle to the file as described by @bland.

Make sure that you dispose your IDisposable's in a timely fashion and this problem may well go away.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using

```cs
Directory.Delete(folderName, true);
```

that should recursively delete?