# Recursively deleting of directories in C# throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I am trying to delete a directory and all its contents like this:

```
    private static void CleanOrCreateDirectory(string directory)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(directory)) Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
```

which should be the standard way, suggested in various answers to related questions on SO. However, it doesn't work. I get:

```
System.IO.IOException : The directory is not empty.
```

Well, of course it is not empty, that is the whole point! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What directory do you try to delete?

Comment: Looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov, a local directory `Data`, that contains some files and folders generated by the tests.

Comment: The problem can be that some process or even your process uses files from that directory, so it can delete them, so directory is also can'be deleted. The other problem can be that it has file with readonly attribute

Comment: I'd use `SHFileOperation` for this

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of IOException causes when calling `Directory.Delete` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

It lists all the distinct reasons why you get an IOException, one would assume the cause is listed there!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the implementation of `Directory.Delete(name, true)` just doesn't do what it says on the tin. For a workaround, see the accepted answer from [Cannot delete directory with Directory.Delete(path, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true).

Thanks @HaunsTM