# After Directory.Delete the Directory.Exists returning true sometimes?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have very weird behavior. I have,

```
Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true);
if (Directory.Exists(tempFolder))
{
}
```

Sometimes Directory.Exists return true. Why?  May be the explorer is open?

Comment: Is it possible the the `Directory` indeed _not deleted_?

Comment: I have never dealt with this... but surely [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true?rq=1) may be of use.

Comment: Maybe your directory still exist

Comment: @NicholasV. doubtful -- that error would have thrown an exception before getting to the OP's `if` statement.

Comment: Is the Directory empty?

Comment: Incidentally, why are you adding an if block to run if the directory exists if you have just deleted it?

Comment: @BanksySan, I have added just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Directory.Delete` calls the Windows API function [`RemoveDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488.aspx). The observed behavior is documented:

> The `RemoveDirectory` function **marks a directory for deletion on close**. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.

The .NET documentation is unfortunately missing this information. Whether the static `Directory.Delete` method opens a handle to the directory is not documented. Likewise, if it does, it is not documented when the handle is closed.

Without any of this information, the best you can do is to poll for completion:

```
Directory.Delete(tempFolder, true);
while (Directory.Exists(tempFolder)) Thread.Sleep(0);
// At this point the directory has been removed from the filesystem
```

Even though polling should generally be avoided in preference of events, installing a filesystem watcher would be a bit over the top for this. Still, keep in mind, that this operation does not come for free, particularly when dealing with a network drive.

---

**Update:** With .NET's [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) available, the implementation of [Directory.Delete](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,7edbf8078ebb7f63) can be inspected. The first action of this method is to iterate over all files and delete them. The iteration is implemented using [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx)/[FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx). The returned handle is stored as a [SafeFindHandle](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/safehandles/safefindhandle.cs), a concrete subclass of [SafeHandle](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs). As the [documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,31) points out, the native handle is freed through a concrete [ReleaseHandle](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,ac84a1b028dd8696) override. ReleaseHandle is called from a (postponed) critical finalizer. Since finalization is non-deterministic, this explains the open handle, responsible for the delayed directory delete.

This information, however, does not help in finding a better solution than the one described above (polling for completion).

---

<sup>Other answers to this question did not identify the core issue, and work by **coincidence** at best. [BanksySan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265630/1889329) adds unrelated code that introduces a delay to allow time for open handles to be closed. [Byeni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265728/1889329) is closer, yet still off: When he talks about *the object referencing the directory* he almost nails it. However, the object referencing the directory is called a *handle*, a native resource. Native resources are disposed of in finalizers, and `GC.Collect()` does not run finalizers. This, too, appears to work by buying extra time.</sup>

Comment: The `SafeFindHandle` is wrapped in a `using`. Are you saying that although `SafeFindHandle` implements `IDisposable`, and the `Dispose()` method gets called, `SafeFindHandle` still saves some of the work for the finalizer?

Comment: @hvd: According to the [documentation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,56) the native handle is freed only after normal finalizers have been run. The `IDisposable` pattern does not run finalizers.

Comment: That's not the documentation, that's a comment. [The documentation is here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) The documentation for the `Dispose()` method states "Releases all resources used by the SafeHandle class." The reference source does not contradict this: both the finalizer and `Dispose()` call external code we can't check. MS would be extremely foolish if they did implement `IDisposable` in such an utterly useless way as you describe, where `Dispose()` does not actually release resources. :)

Comment: @hvd: The documentation for [ReleaseHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.releasehandle.aspx) mandates: *"When overridden in a derived class, executes the code required to free the handle."* The reason, why *`IDisposable` is implemented in an utterly useless way* is also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx): *"a FileStream object can run a normal finalizer to flush out existing buffered data without the risk of the handle being leaked or recycled."*

Comment: You keep pointing out what the finalizers do, but you don't answer the question of whether `Dispose()` does the same thing. You assert that it doesn't, and while I can see how you feel that is supported by the comment block you link to, there still isn't any support for it from either the code or the documentation. Your quote *doesn't* say whether FileStream flushes data during `Dispose()`. It merely says that FileStream flushes data during its finalizer, while leaving open the possibility that other method calls do the same thing.

Comment: @hvd: `Dispose()` cleans up **managed resources**, when called with an argument of `true` (ultimately what the `using` statement does). `Dispose()` frees **unmanaged resources**, when called with an argument of `false`. The latter invokes the finalizer. Finalization is performed by the garbage collector, running out-of-band. This implies, that finalizers won't run when `IDisposable::Close()` is executed. This is essentially the reason why we have finalizers to begin with.

Comment: No. Just plain no. `Dispose()` cleans up managed *and* unmanaged resources. The finalizer cleans up any unmanaged resources that hadn't been cleaned up earlier (possibly because the programmer forgot to call `Dispose()`). That's the standard [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) as documented by Microsoft, anyway.

Comment: @hvd: `Dispose()` calls `Dispose(bool)` (by default). The boolean parameter is used to distinguish, whether the method is called from a finalizer, or as part of regular (deterministic) cleanup. In case of the `SafeHandle` implementation, `Dispose()` calls `Dispose(true)`, skipping cleanup of unmanaged resources. If you insist that this is wrong, please consider whipping out WinDbg, and post your own answer to this question, and share your findings.

Comment: The link I gave you showed you the standard Dispose pattern. You're right that it calls `Dispose(true)`, but the standard Dispose pattern as documented on that page releases unmanaged resources independent of the `disposing` parameter, and managed resources only if `disposing` is `true`. Look for `ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory`: it isn't in any `if` block. The reference source is not complete enough to answer whether `SafeHandle` implements that, and WinDbg is complicated. But sure, I will (later) try to create a simple test application to see how it behaves at runtime.

Comment: If it really is the handle, 'GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()' should be another solution. But some quick tests have shown that it is reproducable even with Collect and Wait (Even with some thread switch before). So there must be something else that prevents the deletion and polling still remains the only way :(

Comment: @sanosdole: See the first quote of my answer: *"The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed."* `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` still does not ensure, that the directory is deleted immediately. The only guarantee is, that it will be deleted at some point after the final handle to the directory has been closed.

Answer (score 8):

Use `DirectoryInfo` instead, and call `Refresh()` on that.

```
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(tempFolder);
        dir.Delete();
        dir.Refresh();
```

Because we are performing many operations on the directory, it is more performant to use `DirectoryInfo` rather that `Directory`.  This probably explains why there is no `Refresh()` on the static class, it is meant for one off operations and so would never need to be refreshed.

If *might* be worth adding a `Thread.Sleep(0)` after the refresh to relinquish the thread and put it to the back of the pool.  Haven't tested that though, it's just a musing.

Comment: May be a good point, but I tried this to solve the original question, and it does not help. Accepted answer seems to work without fail.