# How To Delete Temp File On Any Win CPU

Tags: c#

Today I'm wondering if I could delete a TEMP file. I have the coding to delete the correct path name but it wont work on any other win pc due to only allowing me to using my folder naming on pc.

This is because when I play a mp3 though resources in winforms it wont let me play another song till TEMP file from previous play is deleted.

I'm looking for all files delete to save me from selecting a path name where I prefer to delete all files in the TEMP as I want to share my tool with others.

Heres the coding I'm using

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp"))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Temp");

    MessageBox.Show("TEMP File Deleted");
}
else
{
      MessageBox.Show("Not Done");
}
```

Comment: `Temp` isn't a file, it is a directory...

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that on every other systems the user is also named "g".

Comment: thanks for pointing out some stuff thats needed to know :)

Comment: @AnthonyRaven Don't try to be smart. If you check if a *file* exists and it is in fact a *directory*, it will return false. Your code does work if you change `File` to `Directory`. You could also just truncate `%temp%`, which is shorthand for the temp directory.

Comment: am still learning my c sharp lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetTempPath()` to get the path of the temporary folder, But There may be some files in the temp location are used by another processes, so you should care about the IOExceptions while deleting those files/folders,

```
// for deleting sub directories in temp
foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetTempPath()))
{
    try
    {
        Directory.Delete(subDirectory, true); 
    }
    catch
    {                       
    }
}
// for deleting files in temp

foreach (string tempfile in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetTempPath(),"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
 {
     try
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete(tempfile);
     }
     catch
     {
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much this code as worked for me with no issues. thanks for your support in this....  A.R

Comment: Anyone interested in this answer should also read through this entire thread for more explanations on the behavior of `Directory.Delete`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true

Answer (score 0):

```
cls
@echo off
cd %temp%
del %temp%\*.* /f /s /q 
for /D %%f in (%temp%\*) do rmdir "%%f" /s /q

del c:\windows\temp\*.* /f /s /q
for /D %%f in (c:\windows\temp\*) do rmdir "%%f" /s /q

del C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.* /f /s /q
for /D %%f in (C:\Windows\Prefetch\*) do rmdir "%%f" /s /q

del "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%f in ("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*") do rmdir "%%f" /s /q

del "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" /f /s /q
for /D %%f in ("C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*") do rmdir "%%f" /s /q

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
cls
```

Save this code in a `.bat` file ...

It will clear all the temp or dump files from your system.

Answer (score 0):

for more deep clean use below in ".bat" file

@echo off
del /s /f /q %windir%\temp*.*
rd /s /q %windir%\temp
md %windir%\temp
del /s /f /q %windir%\Prefetch*.*
rd /s /q %windir%\Prefetch
md %windir%\Prefetch
del /s /f /q %windir%\system32\dllcache*.*
rd /s /q %windir%\system32\dllcache
md %windir%\system32\dllcache
del /s /f /q "%SysteDrive%\Temp"*.*
rd /s /q "%SysteDrive%\Temp"
md "%SysteDrive%\Temp"
del /s /f /q %temp%*.*
rd /s /q %temp%
md %temp%
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"*.*
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\History"
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"*.*
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files"
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"*.*
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"
md "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp"
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"*.*
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"
md "%USERPROFILE%\Recent"
del /s /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"*.*
rd /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"
md "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"