# How to find out if other code owns a handle to a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I have a pretty big codebase in .NET 4.7.2 which does a lot of file system manipulation and pretty often calls `Directory.Delete(path, true)` method, which sometimes yields to `IOException` or `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

According to a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1703799/4682601) it's because someone else owns a windows handle to a directory.

The code base is using multiple managed threads and I'd like to find out if some other thread/resource holds a handle to a directory.

Is there a way to accomplish that without actually calling `Directory.Delete` and receiving an exception?

Comment: There is no method in .NET Framework for this. And even if there was, in the time between checking and executing the Delete another process may create or close a handle. It can be done by some low-level techniques as demonstrated by SysInternal's process explorer.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c/5372541