# Is there a way to get the PID from a process that is blocking a file using C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, pid

Is there a way to get the PID from a process that is blocking a file using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether it can be done entirely within the framework, but maybe you could call out to [SysInternals' Handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to do the heavy lifting here?

Comment: +1 for using Handle.exe. It would be very difficult to implement such functionality in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c

Comment: Parsing handle output can be a simple and clean choice.

Thanks :).

Comment: any sample (and real) source code in C# using Handle.exe ?? @Cerebrus, no thanks, only vote