# How to check if a program is using .NET?

Tags: .net, process, executable

Can we check if a running application or a program uses .Net framework to execute itself?

Comment: Crank up Process Monitor and if the executable is highlighted yellow it's a managed application.  Hurr.

Comment: Will, I think you meant Process Explorer ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There's a trick I once learned from Scott Hanselman's [list of interview questions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx). You can easily list all programs running .NET in command prompt by using:

> `tasklist /m "mscor*"`

It will list all processes that have `mscor*` amongst their loaded modules.

We can apply the same method in code:

```
public static bool IsDotNetProcess(this Process process)
{
  var modules = process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().Where(
      m => m.ModuleName.StartsWith("mscor", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

  return modules.Any();
}
```

Comment: Note this does leave out possible Mono processes.

Comment: @Dykam Isn't mono's runtime also called mscorlib.dll ?

Comment: The runtime is just `mono`. Or `mono.exe` on windows. .Net uses PE to let the OS use mscorlib.dll to start the app, but mono doesn't do such a trick. And the real core lib is called corlib.dll I think, as it isn't MS's corlib.

Comment: I don't think this will work anymore for .NET 4.0, the DLLs were renamed.  You'll also get false positives for apps that host the CLR, Visual Studio for example.

Comment: The .NET 4.0 runtime is called clr.dll.

Comment: I tried this, though the process was displayed in the list, IL Disassembler says its not a valid .net assembly.

Comment: Nice trick! But what is with .NET Core applications? I made some tests by myself converting a .net windows application into a .net core application, and the difference seems that .net core uses "System.Runtime.dll"  (`tasklist /m "System.Runtime.dll"`), while .net uses "MSCOREE.DLL" (`tasklist /m "mscor*"`). You can try it yourself: `tasklist /M | find "YourAppName"` finds both versions of your application while they are running.

Comment: Addition: To get both in one command line, I found you can use: `tasklist /FI "modules EQ MSCORE*" & tasklist /FI "modules EQ System.Runtime.dll"` - this will list the .NET applications first, then the .NET Core applications.

Answer (score 11):

Use the CLR COM interfaces ICorPublish and ICorPublishProcess. The easiest way to do this from C# is to borrow some code from SharpDevelop's debugger, and do the following:

```
ICorPublish publish = new ICorPublish();
ICorPublishProcess process;

process = publish.GetProcess(PidToCheck);

if (process == null || !process.IsManaged)
{
    // Not managed.
}
else
{
    // Managed.
}
```

Comment: I was wondering, if you do this from C#, under which conditions will this check report "not managed"?

Comment: It seems that it will only consider managed those processes that have the same CLR used  - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fac08eee-001d-4566-b1e7-fda1ddbc37e7/icorpublishgetprocess-throws-systemargumentexception-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected?forum=netfxtoolsdev. So one should be careful with it.

Answer (score 8):

Use `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` function to load the .exe file. This function will throw exception if you try to load binary file that is not .NET assembly.

Comment: what difference does it make? running application doesn't have .exe file?

Comment: In that case, please show him how to find the EXE file corresponding to the running program; and show him how to deal with the possibility his process can't get read access to the .EXE file.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my answer is not complete and bulletproof and I'm sorry for sarcastic comment.

Comment: This doesn't work if the hosting process is x64 and the exe is x86 only.

Comment: Keep in mind. Loading an assembly allows this assembly to execute code inside your appdomain.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is about a million years too late, but in case it helps - my favourite method to figure out if an exe is using .net is to run MSIL disassembler against it which comes with .net SDK. If a .net exe you indeed have, you'll get a nice graphical breakdown of its contents; if a plain old win32 exe it be, you'll get a message telling you so.

Comment: Good answer.  Specifically, run ILDASM.EXE, which is automatically installed with Visual Studio.  See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx   To launch ILDASM from Win8/VS2013:  Start -> Visual Studio Tools --> Developer Command Prompt for VS2013.  From Win8/VS2012:  Start -> Developer Command -> Developer Command Prompt for VS2012.  From Win7:  All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Programmatically you'd get the starting image name using Win32 API like `NtQueryInformationProcess`, or in .Net use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()`
and read `Process.StartInfo.FileName`.

Then open and decode the PE headers of that image using details prescribed in the MSDN article below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx

Caveats: will only detect .NET built assemblies e.g. won't detect Win32 EXEs dynamically hosting CLR using CorHost APIs.

Answer (score 3):

A list of running .NET processes is available in `Performance Monitor`. Just run `perfmon` and in the **Monitoring Tools >> Performance Monitor** click **+** Icon or press Ctrl+N. In the list of available counters, at the beginning of the list find **.NET CLR Jit** and select a sub item. You will see a list of .NET process in **Instances of selected object** list.

If you want a method in C# without running your app in Administrator mode, there is solution introduced by **Process Hacker** tool.

According to [Process Hacker / .NET Tools / native.c](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/9e25e6a4790531281e52ff975d049e44c27c7261/phlib/native.c) :

> Most .NET processes have a handle open to a section named **\BaseNamedObjects\Cor_Private_IPCBlock(*v4)*<ProcessId>.** This is the same object used by the ICorPublish::GetProcess function. Instead of calling that function, we simply check for the existence of that section object. This means: * Better performance.
>   * No need for admin rights to get .NET status of processes owned by other users.

Getting a list of Process handles in C# [is a bit of hard work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c). Instead you can download the **DotNetTools.dll** from Process Hacker `plugins` folder and create an `extern` method to use `PhGetProcessIsDotNet` function.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest downloading the Redgate's DotNetReflector and checking if it can open the application.