# How do I determine if a Process is Managed in C#?

Tags: c#, process

A bit of searching returns this result: [Which processes are running managed code and which version?](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/18/Which-processes-are-running-managed-code-and-which-version_3F00_-_2800_C_2300_-code-snippet_2900_.aspx)

However I am wondering if there is a 'better' way then simply iterating though the loaded modules? It seems a little quirky to look for the string "mscorwks.dll". Reading though the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) on MSDN doesn't seem to point out an obvious solution.

Assumptions Made

1. .NET 4.0
2. I have a "Process" in hand

Thank you

Comment: Define "managed code".  Java is managed, interpreted languages are managed as well.  Are you interested specifically in .NET assemblies or any type of managed code?

Comment: I don't see it as quirky.  That's the filename of the core library dll.

Comment: @Ed S. Apologies, by 'Managed Code' I mean code running on top of the CLR.

@yodaj007 Is that guaranteed to be the same across all versions of the .NET Framework and for all languages?

Comment: Are you interested in whether the main executable is a .NET assembly, or just whether the process in question hosts a CLR? The latter is the case for managed add-ins in e.g. Windows Explorer or Office applications. And do you need to do this programmatically? Otherwise Process Explorer will highlight all processes hosting a .NET CLR.

Comment: @0xA3 Interesting question, and one I had forgotten all about. If possible I'd like to detect both scenarios. In essence if I could programmatically duplicate what ProcessExplorer does to determine if the process is hosting the .NET CLR that would be ideal.

Comment: Meanwhile you might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any future Googlers: I ended up using the suggested answer posted here [How to check if a program is using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net) (thanks 0xA3!)

```
Process mProcess = //Get Your Process Here
foreach (ProcessModule pm in mProcess.Modules)
{
    if (pm.ModuleName.StartsWith("mscor", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As an aside looking for "mscorwks.dll" as mentioned in my original post does not work for .NET 4.0.

Comment: Or in a single LINQ expression: `return process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().Any(module => module.ModuleName.StartsWith("mscor", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));`.

Answer (score 1):

In code, get the full path of the executing process.
Try to use `Assembly.Load` on the process. If it works, it's a .Net assembly :)

Comment: Security wise not that ideal solution. Keep in mind. If you load an assembly it can execute code inside your appdomain.