# Identifying a process or a module as managed/native

Tags: .net, c++, windows, unmanaged, managed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine if a Process is Managed in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997987/how-do-i-determine-if-a-process-is-managed-in-c)

How can I know if a process or a module is managed (.NET) or native programmatically (in C++)?

Comment: I was hoping for maybe some data in the EXE file itself.

Comment: Use `Assembly.LoadFile`, check for `BadImageFormatException` for unmanaged code

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the PE spec handy - you can download it from msdn.com - but a managed module will typically have a CLR header and imports mscoree.dll.