# Filter .Net processess from all windows processess

Tags: .net, process

Filter all the processes which are running in .net Framework from the processes of windows application,

Comment: There needs to be a question here.  You should also be able to show some good faith effort that you have been working on this issue.  Go to Google first and then come back here with a semi-working example or at least the explanation that you couldn't find anything that looked like it would work.

Comment: You also need to consider some gray areas - e.g. SQL Server, or any application with a general plugin architecture may have loaded .NET due to that plugin, but may not be a .NET framework app itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a program is using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net)

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you would need to look at the DLLs that each running process is using.  I think the common one every .NET application would be using is the mscorlib.dll.  Therefore, if an application is using mscorlib.dll, you can determine that it is a .NET application.  That will give you every process that is running a version of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your comments and Answer.

Atlast i found the answer for my Query.

Use the WMI query in your Code Like.

"SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory"

This will fetch all the .Net Framework Processes in your Application.