# How to detect if my COM object is being used from a .NET application?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, com, com-interop

I have a COM DLL written in Visual C++. I fully control that COM DLL code. Of course it can be consumed from both managed and unmanaged applications. I want to insert a very specific check that should only be run when the COM DLL is consumed by a .NET application.

Is there some programmatic way for my COM object to detect whether it is being consumed from a .NET application or from an unmanaged application?

Comment: @sharptooth I have no idea if it's possible, but I'd love to know why you want to?

Comment: @aphoria: We want to insert an extra check that is only needed when it is used from a .NET application and would hurt otherwise.

Comment: It does seem like a rather odd question.  Maybe you could check if mscoree.dll is loaded, though I'm not sure how reliable of an indicator that is.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net for example (I like wj32's answer).

Comment: @sharptooth: Can you be more specific about that check? Normally, the called COM object shouldn't care what technology is used to implement the caller.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: What I want to check is not that critical - I just want to write an if-statement and don't know which condition to check.

Comment: @sharptooth: I want to understand why this check is needed at all. In other words: Why do you care which technology calls you?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: There're some differences between managed and unmanaged in handling COM interfaces if a library is loaded directly and first object is created by calling an exported function marked `DllImport` instead of using `new` in C#. That's a bad solution, but we have to maintain it.

Answer (score 2):

These kind of "what's my environment" questions always have the same answer.  Your host has no trouble figuring out if it is managed, just add a property to your interface to let it tell you.  A trivial solution compared with the alternative.  Which is impossible to implement reliably in COM, lots of ways to host a server.

Comment: +1 This is a very good point. It's tempting to over-engineer a cool, slick solution when a simple one would work. (Something I struggle with.) This doesn't technically answer the question, but maybe it's not possible and this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. Create a native .NET assembly wrapping the COM object and initializing it appropriately
2. [Try to detect whether your process is a .NET process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net) and live with the problems (no mono detection, false positives, most likely invalid detection when used in the context of DCOM/COM+)