# how can i know which are the application currently executing use the .net framework

Tags: .net, windows

i want to know which of the currently running application is using the .net framework?
is there is and exe or any process that is running??? Need to write program in java to know which of the application uses the .net framework.

Comment: Just a guess, but get a list of the dlls loaded by the application...must be a clue in there.

Comment: The idea behind tagging is *not* to attract a larger community - `java` tag removed from post

Answer (score 2):

You could enumerate the modules loaded in the process. If mscoree.dll is loaded it is more than likely that the application is using .NET Fx.
Check [How to check if a program is using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Dan. One more query I have. Is there any system process/exe/service which uses .Net framework from the system startup itself? I need to trigger another application depending on such a service. It'll be of great help if you could answer this.. Thanks

Comment: I know two types of applications of this kind: Windows services and the applications configured to start when an user logs in. Windows API and also .NET Fx BCL can help you with enumerating the Windows services configured to start automatically; to determine the applications configured to start when an user logs on, see http://windowsxp.mvps.org/Startup.htm. Once you have the list of applications, scan their binary files and check they have the .NET flag set.