# Access denied exception when trying to query modules in a running process

Tags: c#, .net, exception, process

I am trying to get list of running processes that uses .NET. I am using the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net) to do that.

```
using (Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid))
{
     var modules = p.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().Where(
                    m => m.ModuleName.StartsWith("mscor", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
     if (modules.Any())
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} used .NET", pid));
}
```

I am running this program as Administrator. However for some proecsses ( e.g.,  Software Protection process) I get following exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Code\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
```

What I am doing wrong here?