# What versions of.Net are being used

Tags: .net, windows, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there any way to tell what versions of .Net are being used on a server.

I can see what is installed and what is using .Net from 
[How to check if a program is using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080046/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-using-net)

but is there any way to tell which installed versions are being actively used?

Thanks

Comment: All of them. Perhaps you wanted to ask about a specific functionality?

Comment: Just because a version isn't being used *now* doesn't mean the next process to be started won't be using it.

Comment: To make that clearer: listing processes that have loaded .NET only tells you about currently running processes. But to check for all possible uses you would need to check all executables and the libraries they loaded for dependencies. And that wouldn't pick up anything loading .NET dynamically (which is possible even if a rare option).

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why do you want to know this?

Comment: All versions after .NET 4.0 are binary replacements. This means that installing a newer version replaces the older one. There is only *one* 4+ version installed at a time. Versions 2.0 and 3.5 are actually 2.0 with extra libraries. There's only one actual version installed at a time as well.

Comment: I've inherited a legacy system and historic knowledge is low, we have an audit finding to remove unsupported software and am trying to understand the risks involved.