# how can i know file is already open or in use?

Tags: c#, .net, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)
>   [Check if a file is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987559/check-if-a-file-is-open)

how can i know file is already open or in use.

```
public bool FileIsLocked(string strFullFileName)
        {
            bool blnReturn = false;
            System.IO.FileStream fs;
            try
            {
                fs = System.IO.File.Open(strFullFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                blnReturn = true;
            }
            return blnReturn;
        }
```

I find above code it is not working properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c

Comment: Note that the information you get using a function like that, can be obsolete the moment you use it. The file can be locked, the instance you checked that it wasn't and vice versa. Usually it is best to try whatever you need to do with the file, and react to errors when they occur.

Comment: i get this code but it is not work proparly

Comment: dup of a dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162957/determine-if-a-file-is-open

Answer (score 0):

As taken from here: [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Already answers before over here  : [Check if a file is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987559/check-if-a-file-is-open/2987576#2987576)

**Edit**

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
```

**Function**

```
protected virtual bool IsFileinUse(FileInfo file)
{
     FileStream stream = null;

     try
     {
         stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
     }
     catch (IOException)
     {
         //the file is unavailable because it is:
         //still being written to
         //or being processed by another thread
         //or does not exist (has already been processed)
         return true;
     }
     finally
     {
         if (stream != null)
         stream.Close();
     }
     return false; 
}
```

Comment: @bkac  - buts working for me check the file path is same and data is there for you....

Answer (score 0):

Try catching `UnauthorizedAccessException` as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx

`UnauthorizedAccessException` doesn't inherit from `IOException` 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx