# Windows/Python check if file is open or in use

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pywin32, psutil, windows-10-desktop

I am using python to monitor a folder and check if files are being copied in and if so, replicate those to a new location.
I am using the following to monitor the folder:
[fsmonitor](https://github.com/ljmccarthy/fsmonitor)
The issue I am facing is that I am unable to discern if the file is in use and currently in the process of writing the contents onto disk. if so I want to wait till copying is complete and then start copying it to my new location.

So how do I find out if a file is in use/open?
I have seen some suggestions here where I try to write to the file question and if it fails then it indicates that the file is in use:
[example answer (I've seen similar in python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277461/how-can-i-know-file-is-already-open-or-in-use)
But I am reluctant to use such a method due to the fear that it might cause corruption and such issues.
Is there an alternative/safer way to do this? Or is testing write permissions safe?
Is anyone familiar with [pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/index.html)? Does it provide such tools? The site looks arcane, so wonder if it has the latest API provided by windows, even fsmointor mentioned above uses the same library and I wonder if there are newer/more efficient ways to do this.

Currently, I am using psutil, proc.open_files() to loop through all processes and all files to list out open files. if files that I am concerned about appear on this list I wait and try again. However, this process creates a humongous list of files and uses 12% of my CPU to create it, so I desperately need an alternative.

In response to Adrian McCarthy
I starting out assuming that it is safe to action whatever fsmonitor puts out, but if you see the following output which si for a single file copy:

> 0 86 0
> create C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe 3684bf38
> create C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe 3684bf38
> 0 86 0
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe a8cf3250
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe a8cf3250
> 0 160 0
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe caef5c64
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64.exe caef5c64
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64 - Copy.exe caef5c64
> modify C:\Users\ScanUser\Pictures\syncTest dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64.exe caef5c64

So the conundrum is at which 'modify' do I start copying the file? I can wait a few minutes/seconds to see if another 'modified' appeared for that file but how do I decide the time to wait for a large file over SFTP may take 30 minutes, so I need something scalable.
Also, I would like not the make multiple copy actions for a file since that will make the script inefficient.

Comment: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you
[check if a file is open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python)
here is a code:

```py
try: # try to open the file
   with open("file", "r") as file: 
       # some code here
except IOError:
   # if it throws an error that means it is in use
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're unnecessarily concerned about working with the file while another process still has it open.

On Windows. `fsmonitor` using the ReadDirectoryChangesW mechanism.  That means you'll get a notification about a change *after* it happens.  So if a process writes to `foo.log`, you'll get a notification after the write operation is completed.  (In fact, I think it's after the update of the directory metadata.)

To copy the file, you need read access.  So just go ahead and open it for reading.

If it opens, then it's safe to read, even if another process has it open.  You cannot corrupt a file by reading it even if another process is writing to it.

If it fails to open, then another process has it open and is intentionally preventing other processes from reading it (probably because they know they'll be actively updating it).  In that case, you can try again later.

Trying to first check whether another process is using the file doesn't actually help because the answer could change between the moment you check and the moment you try to act on that information.
When you open a file, the system does the permission check and the opening under a mutex<sup>*</sup>, so the answer cannot change in between.  There's no way for you to simulate that yourself from user-mode code.  Once you have the file open, you can safely use it.

If you try to read from a file at the same moment another process tries to write to it, the system will ensure that the read will get the data as it was before the write or as it is after the write.  It won't get a result that's a mixture of old and new.

That said, if you're reading the file with a bunch of small read operations while another process is writing to the file with a bunch of small write operations, it's possible you might capture some intermediate state of the file.  But that's okay.  The original file is unharmed, and those writes will trigger another fsmonitor notification, so you're code will start over and try to make another copy of the file.

---

<sup>*</sup> I'm using "mutex" in a generic sense:  It uses some sort of synchronization mechanism, but it might not necessarily be a Windows Mutex object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've update the question with more information