# Get current open filename from Windows Process using C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there a way to find the currently open file from an Excel or Word process?
For example, i want to get all the list of running processes in windows and which files they currently have open.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c). See the [sample on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170) mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking for the currently open word/excel document (presumably from within a C# plugin) or are you asking for a list of all processes?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of how to programmaticly do this, but if you are asking in general or looking for a tool to do it [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can under "View Handles" and look for the type "File". You can also see which program has a specific file open by clicking the binoculars.

Comment: In other words--it's a log of ugly low-level programming if you had to code it yourself.