# List open files by process

Tags: c#, file, process, handles

Assuming I have the pid or process name, how can I get the open files by that process in c#? The question has been asked before but I couldn't find what I was looking for.
I know that each process probably will have many handles but I can filter them out later. So, is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c)

Comment: @ Yuriy Faktorovich I have seen that post already but it wasn't helpful for me

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich Because one proposed working solution was about monitoring folders which is not what I want

Comment: Consider this class DetectOpenFiles : http://vmccontroller.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/47386#195318