# How to view which files is Writing a Process

Tags: c#, windows, file, process, trace

Is there a way to get List of Files or FileName which a Process is writing (if possible writing/reading/appending) ,from C# ,which means im talking about Windows (NT,Vista,XP,7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here: [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c)