# Monitor files accessed by other programs

Tags: c#, .net, monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor (and read) files that are created or accessed by another program. I found an approach in [this article](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-online-poker-bot-7). However, this article uses a C++ solution that is embedded in a C# program.

Is there a native C# solution for this monitoring job?

(Sorry if this has been asked before. I just couldn't find anything similar enough.)

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c

Comment: Do you need to know when a file handle is open? whether the file is actually changed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably look into [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). I haven't used it yet, but seems that this sort of thing is what it is for:

> Use FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a specified directory.
>   You can watch for changes in files and subdirectories of the specified
>   directory. You can create a component to watch files on a local
>   computer, a network drive, or a remote computer.

Comment: Thanks alot. It seems to work. Using the FileSystemWatcher class was easier than I expected.