# taglib# cannot save changes

Tags: c#, taglib, taglib-sharp

I would like to tag some existing mp3 with taglib#.
I have the following error message:
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
I don't know what kind of process it can be. I can access any mp3 files on any of my hard drives, I also can use the properties of the file, but I cannot save changes.

This is the code.

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
if ((bool)f.ShowDialog())
{
   try
   {
       if ( f.OpenFile() != null)
       {

       TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(f.FileName);                            
       file.Tag.Album = "Album1";
       file.Save();

       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");
}
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: If that's really your error, your question is more of finding out what's using the MP3 file. Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c help? Unless, you're not opening the Stream with Write access? It's odd that unused MP3 are being used.

Comment: `f.OpenFile()` will never return `null`.

Comment: Why do you think clicking Cancel means `Problem occured`?

Answer (score 2):

`f.OpenFile()` creates a `FileStream` around the file.
Since you never close this stream, the file remains open.

Don't do that.