# How to find all opened files of word or excel

Tags: c#

How to find the full path of all opened files of different applications i.e Word, pdf reader or Excel?
I tried attached code, but only found the file names rather then complete path of files.

```
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"))
            try
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("======================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Window Title:" + p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Process Name:" + p.ProcessName.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Window Handle:" +  p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());     
                }
            }
            catch { }
```

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/177146/1380061

Comment: Note that some applications can open multiple files, so a single value will not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Console.WriteLine("Full Path:" +  p.MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: this returns the full path to application, not the full paths by the files currently open by the application, which is what is asked for, I believe (hard to tell actually..)