# Get file name of opened document using c#

Tags: c#, file-io, path

In my application I need to get the filename of the file which is opened. I found several threads about how to get the name of the process which is running but nothing about how I can get the file name (or path, at least I need the file name) of the current opened document.

I know how I can get the path:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName)
string path = info.FullName;
```

But to use this I need the string "fileName" which is the name of the current opened file.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Because it's not easy. You have to enumerate handles of a given process, select file handles and then find to what they refer. All done with unmanaged APIs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path of the file, then you can use the following code to get the filename:

```
string path = string.Empty;
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the path. It is dynamically set

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for that you should P/Invoke:
try GetFileInformationByHandleEx [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953%28VS.85%29.aspx), that requires the file handle to work with.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this function , give it the path of the file, it will return you false if the file is open,**

```
public bool ckIsFileOpnen(string sFileFullPath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = new FileStream(sFileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                {
                }
                return true; //file is available for write
            }
            catch { }

            return false;
        }
```