# Is it possible to end a Microsoft Word Process according to the File being viewed?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need to kill all Microsoft Word processes on a specific file

I have an overnight job that opens files and edits them then closes them again.

```
private void killprocess(string p)
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(p).OrderBy(x=>x.Id))
    {               
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
```

This method kills all processes with specific name, in this case p="winword"
BUT... I would like to kill all processes where p="winword" and FilePath = "C:\Temp\Test.docx". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the user double clicked the file and opened WinWord then it will be passed as the commandline.

You can try the following:

```
private static void Killprocess(string processName, string expectedCommandLine)
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).OrderBy(x => x.Id))
    {
        var commandLine = GetCommandLine(proc);
        if (commandLine.Contains(expectedCommandLine))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
}

private static string GetCommandLine(Process process)
{
    string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where ProcessId={0}", process.Id);
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection result = searcher.Get();
    return result.Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Select(x => x["CommandLine"].ToString())
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

private static void Main()
{
    Killprocess("winword", yourfullFilePath);
}
```

Note: It needs more work if user opened the file through menu. [You need to find whether a process(Winword) has open file handle to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c) you're concerned about. Once you found that you can kill it.

Comment: That assumes the document name is on the command line, which might be, but not really necessarily.

Comment: @GSerg Could you point an instance of which that would fail? Commandline with the file passed is for that purpose only. I have no idea about when it could fail. If you need it more reliable way go through the link I suggested in note section. That should do the trick.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Whenever the file is opened not via command line - which includes user interface and automation.

Comment: @GSerg That's what I already mentioned in my answer(Note: It needs more work if user opened the file through menu). Read my answer fully please.

Comment: hmmm so there wouldn't be a way to close the file of the word file opened programatically? I am using automation to open the files

Comment: @WisaniManganye There is no easy way AFAIK, did you checked the link I provided in note section? That should help you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I checked it but isn't very helpful as the Project mentioned in that link is written in a language I don't understand so I cant even replicate code

Answer (score 0):

```
private void KillWordByDocumentName(string FullPath)
{
    object document = null;
    object word = null;

    try
    {
        document = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject(FullPath, null);

        word = document.GetType().InvokeMember("Parent", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, document, null);
        word.GetType().InvokeMember("Quit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, null, word, new object[] { true });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        // No words are running
    }
    finally
    {
        if (document != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(document);
        if (word != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(word);
    }
}
```

More work is needed if Word resists to killing (e.g. getting a process ID out of the object and killing that).
Excel is much better than Word in this regard, it directly exposes a `hWnd`.