# Hashing a file and detecting it using C#

Tags: c#, security, hash

I have a question on hashing in C#, is their a way to detect a hashed file what is running as a process or something along those lines.

I am looking into hashing a exe or any other file format and I want to know if there is a way to detect it running within C#.

Comment: Please clarify what you actually trying to do (avoid adding unrelated text like "thank you", "new here", "searched a lot").

Comment: Do you mean hashing, which reduces all files to a (generally) much smaller fixed size hash or do you mean encrypting a file?  An encrypted file can be restored to its original state, since encrypting is a reversible process.  A hash cannot be restored, since hashing is a one way process.

Comment: I want to hash a file what gives it a unique digital signature and then develop a simple algorithm/logic to detect if that file is running/been used. Think of it like a anti virus what will detect signatures of malware and do the specific instruction when detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hashing use `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5` or `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1`.

```
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("myFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(fs);
fs.Close();
```

If you want to analyse all running processes, you can do the following (note that if your process is 32 Bits, you won't be able to access 64 Bits processes):

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    try
    {
        string exePath = proc.MainModule.FileName;
        // calculate hash
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

If you want to get the list of all files being used, you can look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c), but it will be a thought one.

Comment: I do not understand the <MainModule.FileName> section, I been looking into a way to store binary exe files for me to then hash and write some logic to detect the stored hashed files.

Comment: Ah never mind, now I understand whats it doing. Thanks for the info :)