# C# monitor accessing / reading files

Tags: c#, memory, io, monitoring, sysinternals

I want to get list of reading files at the moment
If I open a.txt with notepad, I want to capture it in my C# application
To be more clear, something like Sysinternals Process Monitor

```
7zFM.exe    1264    ReadFile    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ProcessMonitor.zip    SUCCESS
7zFM.exe    1264    ReadFile    C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll   SUCCESS
```

I need to get `C:\Users\User\Desktop\ProcessMonitor.zip` and `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll` for example
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c)

Comment: But I don't know file names, I want to get all file handles