# Get path of files opened by adobe reader

Tags: c#, file, pdf, adobe

Is it possible to get the path of files that are opened by adobe reader in C#?

Comment: `c#`? Perhaps.  `c++`? Definitely.  _Sysinternals Process Explorer_ can after all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the list of open file handles by process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c)