# How to dispose enterprise architect project file?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect, I can use the .NET C# API to open an EA file and then extract some info. This is working as expected. However, when I'm done extracting info using the EA COM Interop API, and my .NET app is terminated, I still have EA processes running. Thus, when I do

```
var repo = new EA.RepositoryClass();
repo.OpenFile(@"c:\Test.eapx");
// extract info
```

I expect to call

```
repo.Dispose();
```

or something along those lines. I do have a

```
repo.CloseFile();
```

but that does not kill the EA process.

How to cleanup my EA resources?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Unfortunately, does not cause the ea process to die.

Comment: I do not know this API, but generally you can try to look for EA in running processes that have a handle to a specific eapx file. Maybe it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177146/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EA process should stop on it's own once the EA objects run out of scope and are garbage collected.

If you can't or don't want to wait for that you can use `EA.Repository.Exit()`

[Documentation](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/repository3.html):

> Exit
>
> Notes: Shuts down Enterprise Architect immediately. Used by .NET
>   programmers where the garbage collector does not immediately release
>   all referenced COM objects.